# Can a President of the United States be arrested for previous crimes?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, president

Recently, the FBI decided not to recommend prosecution of Hillary Clinton, and as of 12:00 noon EST Clinton is projected to have lost her bid for POTUS. However - if the FBI had recommended prosecution and Hillary had won the election, what would the result have been?

I don't know how the US legal system works, but if it would have taken time for her to be convicted, she could have been sworn in as POTUS before being imprisoned, if guilty.

Could she have been arrested after she was sworn in? Or does the POTUS have immunity?

Comment: The trial referenced appears to be a civil trial. These typically do not result in jail time. That does not address the substance of your question but it makes the example possibly unhelpful. A better example would be, if the FBI had recommended prosecution of Clinton and she had won, what would happen?

Comment: @Patrick87 Okay, sure. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: Edits made, please take a look at my changes and see whether I have maintained the essence of your question while only changing the specific (hypothetical) example given to motivate it.

Comment: @Patrick87 Now I am curious about civil trials: does the President, as the commander in chief of the military, enjoy the deferment of civil lawsuits until the end of their service per the Servicemembers Civil Relief Act?

Comment: @user662852 I think that is a worthy question in its own right. This StackExchange would seem an appropriate place to ask it.

Comment: @user662852 the SCRA would not be relevant because the President is not a service member as defined in the act (or under any other definition of which I'm aware; the point of the arrangement is to have a *civilian* commander in chief).

Answer (score 3):

There is no definitive answer, which can only be determined by SCOTUS if faced with a case. [DOJ has opined](https://www.justice.gov/sites/default/files/olc/opinions/2000/10/31/op-olc-v024-p0222.pdf) twice that "the  indictment  or criminal  prosecution of a sitting President would impermissibly undermine the capacity of the executive branch  to  perform  its  constitutionally  assigned  functions". The Impeachment Clause (art.I, §3, cl.7) says

> Judgment  in  Cases  of  Impeachment  shall  not  extend  further 
>   than  to removal from  Office,  and disqualification  to  hold  and
>   enjoy  any  Office  of  honor,  Trust  or  Profit  under  the  United 
>   States:  but  the  Party  convicted  shall  nevertheless  be  liable 
>   and  subject  to  Indict­ment, Trial, Judgment and Punishment,
>   according to Law

The exegesis of this clause is that this means a sitting president cannot first be prosecuted for a crime, but must first be removed from office. The counter-argument is that "nevertheless" indicates that this clause only states that a president can be removed *and then* prosecuted, and that removal does not preclude further action. In other words, the law has yet to be determined on this matter.

Comment: But, before removal, couldn't they give themselves a Ford-Nixon style "pardon of all future charges relating to ______" and then immediately resign?